# DAX reverse filter

Tags: filter, powerbi, dax

Working in Power BI -- pretty straight forward, looking to do the exact opposite of the formula below:

```
newtable = CALCULATETABLE(
                table1, FILTER(
                     table2, table2[ID]
                )
           )
```

Right now this is filtering 675 of 4423 rows in Table 1 that were found in Table 2. I want it to do the exact opposite: 3748 of 4423 rows in Table 1 NOT found in Table 2.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following DAX:

```
newtable = 
CALCULATETABLE(
    table1,
    NOT(table1[ID] IN VALUES(table2[ID]))
)
```

Results:

[image: not in]

Comment: Hi @jake-handy this help solving the issue after all? If so, you can [accept this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/313506) to positively close the question.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is EXCEPT function:

```
EXCEPT( BigTable, SmallTable )
```

This will return a BigTable without elements of SmallTable.

EXCEPT by Alberto:

https://youtu.be/Kk7_TdmxQOI